# The Title of my first widget is behaving like a link

Tags: wordpress

The the title of my widget is behaving like a link I tried to remove it change the order but the one on the top behaves like a link. In this image Recent Posts behaves like a link[image: The image of my widget tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you use tow different widget registered in your wp admin panel

may be your registerd widget `before_title after_title` code contain the anchor html tag.
i use this code below it is work without problems

Use Header Html tags in `before_title` and `after_title` and Don't use Html Anchor tags within Header tags. to avoid Widget Link Title in your theme

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __('Widget Name', 'theme_name'),
    'description'   => __('widget discreption.', 'Theme Name'),
    'id'            => 'widget_id',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
));
```

Comment: You can put your registered widget code that contain the recent post widget? until show the code and help you